# WSO2 BPS - How can I create a human task instance using SOAP?

Tags: soap, wso2

I need to create a task, as in start an instance of a human task, so it appears in the My Tasks list. Is this even possible without having it linked to a process instance? It's just that I only need the Human Task processor as I'm using another program to handle the process. So in my other program it'll go through the workflow and then when it reaches a user task it creates the task in WSO2 BPS so it can be completed.

I'm using generated stubs in Eclipse for the SOAP requests.

Answer (score 1):

This is supported. Just invoke Task service as normal web service using  stubs (wsdl2java) or any other way (like SOAPUI). It will create a Humantask.

Comment: I've figured it out now thanks to your help. I generated stubs using the human task's wsdl and invoking the method, in my case "approve()", which starts it.